# Keep only 2 decimals after comma in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, decimalformat

I'm doing a very simple operation.
Here's the code:

```
float expectedTotal = 32.97;
float firstPrice = 7.99;
expectedTotal -= firstPrice;
```

When I assert that, expectedTotal should be 24.98, but I end up with an error saying:

```
expected [24.980001] but found [24.98]
```

So the first question would be: Where is this 0.000001 comes from?

I have read in other stackoverflow that dealing with currencies is not ideal with float and I should use the DecimalFormat.
I tried with the following code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String s = String.valueOf(expectedTotal);
String newString = df.format(s);
expectedTotal = Float.valueOf(newString);
```

But receive the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
```

I also tried with a parse:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String s = df.format(expectedTotal);
        try {
            expectedTotal = (float) df.parse(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Basically, all I want is `expectedTotal` as a float with only 2 decimals.
Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Masterhaend: I don't see how that answers the formatting question, though.

Comment: Do you want to store it, or just print it?  `System.out.printf("%.2f", myNumber)`.  For what it's worth, you probably shouldn't be storing money as a `float`.

Comment: Gonna say that this is likely a duplicate of the floating point math issue.  Floats have a specific amount of precision; "two decimals" is a convenience for your presentation.

Comment: Use an `int` or `long`, and store pennies.  You won't have these problems.

Comment: I don't want to print it no. I need this variable in an Assert later in my code. That's why I need it to be precise.

Comment: Pass the double value to `format`, not a string version of it. `String newString = df.format(expectedTotal );`

Comment: I can't use an int. I need the decimals behind the commas :/

Comment: Java Use EEE standard for double so when you add 0.1+0.1+0.1 the result is 0.30000000000000004
```
System.out.println((0.1+0.1+0.1));

0.30000000000000004
```

if you need more accuracy you should work with

java.lang.BigDecimal

Comment: BigDecimal expectedTotal = new BigDecimal( 32.97);
  BigDecimal firstPrice = new BigDecimal( 7.99);
  expectedTotal.subtract(firstPrice);

Comment: To summarize the comments: (A) Floating point technology used in the `float`/`Float` & `double`/`Double` types [**trades away accuracy**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. (B) Never use floating-point where accuracy matters. So, **never use floating-point for money**. Either use the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, or use integers representing a count of whole pennies, fractional pennies, or whatever granularity is appropriate in your situation.